# Обработка событий в ООП

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Имеется `javascript` код в ООП "стиле". В объекте `this.callbacks` содержатся функции, которые необходимо вызвать, когда срабатывают события в объекте `eventHandler`.

Допустим, пользователь вводит значение в input и должно сработать событие `keyup`, которое вызывает функцию `getMatches`.

Проблема в том, что функция `Plugin` вызывается только один раз при загрузке страницы и ничего не возвращает, вследствие этого, в дальнейшем, события (`keyup`, `focus`) не срабатывают.

Необходимо каким-то образом внедрить этот код в страницу, чтобы он обрабатывался (вызывался) всегда, как в функциональном стиле.

Код JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Plugin(); //Вызывается 1 раз, при загрузке документа
});

var Plugin = function () {

var self = this;

this.callbacks = {
    findCities: {
        City: function (id, city) {
            //Do something...
        },
        getMatches: function (input) {
            //Do something...
        }
    },
    eventHandler: {
        keyup: function () {
            $('example-div').keyup(function (e) { // не срабатывает
                self.callbacks.findCities.getMatches(this);
            })
        },
        focus: function () {
            $('example-div').focus(function (e) { // не срабатывает
                var city = new self.callbacks.findCities.City(0, 'Moscow');
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Я мог бы написать этот код в обычном функциональном "стиле".

Что-то вроде этого (и это будет работать):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('example-div').keyup(function (e) { 
        getMatches(this);
    });

    $('example-div').focus(function (e) {
        var city = new City(0, 'Moscow');
    });
});

function City(id, city) {
    //Do something...
}

function getMatches(input) {
    //Do something...
}
```

Comment: на мой взгляд тут нет ООП совсем.

Comment: ой вэй... неверный вызов _Plugin_ В данном случае `Plugin` это **не функция, а конструктор**. Для **навешивания** нужно вызвать  _eventHandler.keyup()_ и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за поправку. Действительно, я ошибся в том, что Plugin - это конструктор, а не функция. Но суть не в этом. Мне необходимо понять, как реализовать постоянную обработку функции, при загрузке страницы. То есть, вызвал её один раз, и она обрабатывает события (это похоже на то, как работают jquery плагины).

Comment: @АлександрСиницын - Вам же ответили: путем вызова `this.callbacks.eventHandler.keyup();` в конце `Plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так(но непонятно, при чём тут ООП):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Plugin(); //Вызывается 1 раз, при загрузке документа
});

function Plugin() {
    var callbacks = {
        findCities: {
            City: function (id, city) {
                //Do something...
            },
            getMatches: function (input) {
                //Do something...
            }
        }
    };
    $('example-div').keyup(function (e) { // не срабатывает
        callbacks.findCities.getMatches(this);
    });
    $('example-div').focus(function (e) { // не срабатывает
        var city = new callbacks.findCities.City(0, 'Moscow');
    });

};
```